# Create Approval workflow for Blog in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am facing problem in creating a simple workflow for "Blogs". If a user writes one blog, then his/her manager would be responsible for "Approving/Rejecting" it.

I am using SharePoint Designer, workflow is created but no edit form is created.

Comment: Associate the workflow on item created. Are you using Start Approval Process activity?

Comment: using sharepoint designer and on workflow on created.

Comment: Yes in the designer, have you added "Start Approval Process" activity?

Comment: i am not using Visual Studio

Comment: Amal, can you provide some links that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an approval workflow in SharePoint Desginer.

1. Open the Microsoft SharePoint Designer.
2. Click on File tab and Open your SharePoint site.
3. Click on Workflows
4. Click on List Workflow and Select the blog library where you want the workflow to be  associated
5. Next you can add "Action" -> "Start Approval Process"
6. Select the approver details
7. Save and publish

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/16/a-sample-approval-workflow-which-can-be-recalled-by-initiator.aspx